# Why my pointer becomes dangling pointer in c++?

Tags: c++

My main language is C#, and I'm learning opengl with scarce c++ background.

```cpp
// readShaderSource returns const string

// no warning
auto vShaderStr = readShaderSource("vshader.glsl");
auto vShaderSource = vShaderStr.c_str();

// dangling pointer warning
auto vShaderSource = readShaderSource("vshader.glsl").c_str();
```

What I thought about dangling pointer is something like this:

```cpp
int* a()
{
    auto a = 10;
    return &a

    // a dies here, so &a becomes dangling pointer
}
```

which does not seem to be the case.

Why should I have to go through string variable? Isn't it okay to directly access member function? Is there something to do with return value optimization? I'm pretty confused...

Comment: In `auto vShaderSource = readShaderSource("vshader.glsl").c_str();` the `readShaderSource` functions returns a temporary string.  The `c_str()` accesses an internal representation of that temporary string.  The temporary string is destroyed at the `;`, which also destroys the internal representation which is still referred to by `vShaderSource` ... a dangling pointer.  Dereferencing that dangling pointer is *sad panda*.

Comment: If `readShaderSource` returns `std::string`, when do you think, it is destroyed, in `auto vShaderSource = readShaderSource("vshader.glsl").c_str();`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What I thought about dangling pointer is something like this ... which does not seem to be the case.

It is the same case, actually.  Just in a different form.

The pointer returned by `std::string::c_str()` is valid only for as long as the `std::string` object remains alive (and unmodified).

`readShaderSource()` returns a *temporary* `std::string` object.  That temporary goes out of scope and is destroyed at the end of the full statement that calls `readShaderSource()`.

So, in this code:

```cpp
auto vShaderSource = readShaderSource("vshader.glsl").c_str();
```

The temporary `std::string` object goes out of scope and is destroyed on the `;` after `c_str()` exits.  Thus you are left with a dangling pointer to freed memory.

Whereas in this code:

```cpp
auto vShaderStr = readShaderSource("vshader.glsl");
auto vShaderSource = vShaderStr.c_str();
```

You are saving the temporary `std::string` to a local variable, and then the temporary is destroyed on the `;` after `readShaderSource()` exits.  You are then calling `c_str()` on that local variable, so the returned pointer will remain valid for as long as that local variable remains in scope.

Comment: Ah, my c#-tic brain loses a point again... I think I've got it. Assigning to the local variable extends it's lifespan. Simple but hard...

Comment: @MyBug18 "_Assigning to local variable extends it's lifespan._" Not really. In this case, it makes a copy of said string.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius "*In this case, it makes a copy of said string*" - old versions of C++ would copy. In C++11 and later, it would actually move the returned string instead, or even [optimize away](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) the temporary completely so that `readShaderSource()` initializes `vShaderStr` directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau To to be slightly more precise, the temporary could be optimised away before C++11 as well. And also, since C++17 there wouldn't be a temporary.

Comment: @eerorika "*the temporary could be optimised away before C++11 as well*" - could be, but was not guaranteed until C++17.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, I figured that it might move, yes. But didn't figure out how to define it clearly, in few words :/ Thing that you copy-to is called a copy. How would one call something, that you move-to? :/ So, I thought, that the concept of it, would be more closely related to a thing, called "copy", than an "object with extended lifetime".

Comment: aaand you can bind to const reference: `const std::string &ShaderStr = readShaderSource("vshader.glsl");`, in this case it's an extene lifetime (until refences will go out f scope)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, just like after C++11, and before C++17. Technically, there is no "guarantee of optimisation" in C++17 either, since there isn't a temporary and thus no need to optimise it away. But that's not very important distinction.